# Not able to wrap values in quotes when exporting CQL table to CSV

Tags: csv, cassandra, copy

I am not able to copy data into csv file and have them wrapped with single quote:

e.g.

**Table**: myks.mytable

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 |

**command used:**
copy myks.mytable (column1,column2) to 'myfile.csv' WITH HEADER=FALSE AND DELIMITER=';' AND QUOTE='"';

**expected result:**

csv file to have one row: "value1";"value2"

**actual result:**

csv has one row: value1:value2

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. If you post it there, I'd be happy to help. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Erick for the hint, I just opened a post in dba.stacjexchange.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/315780/not-able-to-wrap-values-in-quotes-when-exporting-cql-table-to-csv